# Select n number of samples from parent samples

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a hierarchy of samples. Field sample_number is key and parent samples are identified 
by the field parent_aliquot. There is anywhere between 0 and 20 aliquot samples for a given parent sample. Each aliquot sample is also indexed within its parent sample by field aliquot_number.
I can select all aliquots for parent samples:

```
select s2.sample_number, s1.sample_number, s1.aliquot_number
from sample s1
inner join sample s2 on s2.sample_number = s1.parent_aliquot
order by s2.sample_number, s1.aliquot_number desc
```

But I would like to select all aliquot samples but 2 (or n) for each parent sample, leaving the two samples with lowest aliquot_number (which might not be 1 and 2).
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in following:

```
select sample_number, sample_number, aliquot_number
from (
   select s2.sample_number, s1.sample_number, s1.aliquot_number,
          row_number() over(partition by parent_aliquot order by aliquot_number) rn
   from sample s1
   inner join sample s2 on s2.sample_number = s1.parent_aliquot
     )x
where rn <= 2 -- here you specify how many rows you want to retrieve
order by sample_number, aliquot_number desc
```